# How to make a simple score system for my game?

Tags: game-design

I'm making a simple game and I can't seem to impliment a simple score system. As the object moves 10 units forward the score should increase by 10. My issue is that when I turn the object around and move backwards the score decreases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just store the maximum seen z value, and then calculate the score with a division, a floor and then a multiplication:

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <cmath>

maxZ = std::max(currentZ, maxZ)
const int score = static_cast<int>(std::floor(maxZ / 10.0f)) * 10;
```

See a graph of this here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/39z7sfnhas